# Manipulate Row corresponding to MIN(Date) to a Default value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, group-by, case

Table T

```
+----+------------+----------+----------+----------+----+----+----+
| ID |   Sdate    |    Pr    |   Oxy    |   Met    | D1 | D2 | D3 |
+----+------------+----------+----------+----------+----+----+----+
|  1 | 7/14/2016  | Negative | Positive | Negative | N  | P  | N  |
|  1 | 8/10/2016  | Positive | Negative | Negative | P  | N  | N  |
|  1 | 9/23/2016  | Positive | Positive | Negative | P  | P  | N  |
|  2 | 6/17/2015  | Negative | Negative | Negative | N  | N  | N  |
|  2 | 8/1/2015   | Negative | Positive | Positive | N  | P  | P  |
|  2 | 11/19/2015 | Positive | Negative | Negative | P  | N  | N  |
|  3 | 2/28/2016  | Negative | Positive | Positive | N  | P  | P  |
|  3 | 4/3/2016   | Positive | Positive | Negative | P  | P  | N  |
+----+------------+----------+----------+----------+----+----+----+
```

I need to default the rows corresponding to the minimum dates within each group to show all values for D1, D2, D3 AS `P` and set remaining values in group to something else

*Desired Output:*

```
+----+------------+----------+----------+----------+----+----+----+
| ID |   Sdate    |    Pr    |   Oxy    |   Met    | D1 | D2 | D3 |
+----+------------+----------+----------+----------+----+----+----+
|  1 | 7/14/2016  | Negative | Positive | Negative | P  | P  | P  |
|  1 | 8/10/2016  | Positive | Negative | Negative | P  | N  | N  |
|  1 | 9/23/2016  | Positive | Positive | Negative | P  | P  | N  |
|  2 | 6/17/2015  | Negative | Negative | Negative | P  | P  | P  |
|  2 | 8/1/2015   | Negative | Positive | Positive | N  | P  | P  |
|  2 | 11/19/2015 | Positive | Negative | Negative | P  | N  | N  |
|  3 | 2/28/2016  | Negative | Positive | Positive | P  | P  | P  |
|  3 | 4/3/2016   | Positive | Positive | Negative | P  | P  | N  |
+----+------------+----------+----------+----------+----+----+----+
```

Code Attempt:

```
SELECT
    ID
    ,SDate
    ,CASE WHEN T.Pr = 'Positive' THEN 'P' ELSE 'N' END AS D1
    ,CASE WHEN T.Oxy = 'Positive' THEN 'P' ELSE 'N' END AS D2
    ,CASE WHEN T.Met = 'Positive' THEN 'P' ELSE 'N' END AS D3
FROM T
```

Not sure how to use `GROUP BY` for ID's and then nest CASE like

`CASE WHEN MIN(DATE) THEN 'P' ELSE CASE WHEN T.Pr...(and so on)`

Any alternative method would also be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is Pr? What is Oxy? What is Met?

Comment: Just different fields in the resultant joined table which I don't need to display as is. Only this simplified result from a sample table I've created.

Comment: You used those columns in your code attempt, then you are saying that those are not necessary? And if they are not necessary, can you explain why each row+column get its value.

Comment: Didn't think it would be particularly useful to include them but Edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #TMP(ID INT
                    ,Sdate dATE
                    ,D1 CHAR(1)
                    ,D2 CHAR(1)
                    ,D3 CHAR(1)
                    )
INSERT INTO #TMP
VALUES
    (1,'20160714','N','P','N')
    ,(1,'20160810','P','N','N')
    ,(1,'20160923','P','P','N')
    ,(2,'20150617','N','N','N')
    ,(2,'20150801','N','P','P')
    ,(2,'20151119','P','N','N')
    ,(3,'20160228','N','P','P')
    ,(3,'20160403','P','P','N')

SELECT 
    A.ID
    ,A.Sdate
    ,CASE WHEN A.Sdate = C.Sdate THEN 'P' ELSE A.D1 END AS D1
    ,CASE WHEN A.Sdate = C.Sdate THEN 'P' ELSE A.D2 END AS D2
    ,CASE WHEN A.Sdate = C.Sdate THEN 'P' ELSE A.D3 END AS D3
FROM
    #TMP A
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ID,SDate FROM #TMP B WHERE A.ID=B.ID ORDER BY Sdate ASC) C
```

Comment: Formatting all sorted now